# Selection of chassis/ cabinet/ case and PSU when assembling a custom server

Tags: hardware

I am planning to assemble servers with primary objective of virtualization. Currently the first machine I wish to set up is tower server with following configuration:

1. **Processor** Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2620 95W **x** 2
2. **Heat Sink** Intel Heat Sink AUPSRCBTP **x** 2
3. **Mother Board** Intel® Server Board S2600CP2 Form Factor SSI EEB 12" x 13" 135W **x** 1
4. **RAM** Kingston 64 GB 1.5V ECC Registered DDR3 KVR16R11D4K4/64 26.4W **x** 4
5. **HDD** Seagate Constellation ES ST1000NM0011 1 TB 7.4W **x** 4

Now, I am unable to find enough guidance online for selection of Cabinet and PSU.

Starting with PSU, I am doing a rough calculation based on max power consumption of each component like 95W x 2 + 135W x 1 + 26.4W x 4 + 7.4W x 4 which comes to roughly 460W and assuming additional power required by CPU and Cabinet Fans I think a 500W-550W PSU should be sufficient for this configuration. I want to know if this calculation is correct or I am missing something important that should be added to the calculation ? Apart from this, for the motherboard do I need something specific to SSI EEB boards like special power connectors etc ?

Going ahead to chassis/ cabinet/ case, I am unable to find any enclosure that includes SSI EEB 12" x 13" board natively and most of them need drilling few extra holes to make EATX cabinet compatible for SSI EEB form factor. How can I overcome this problem ?

I have also gone through Intel Server System http://ark.intel.com/products/56412/Intel-Server-System-P4308CP4MHEN but I don't know if there is any point in spending extra $200-250 because the same configuration can be assembled. Any plus points for this Intel Server System over assembled counterparts ?

As of now, I have selected following Enclosure and PSU:

1. Cooler Master HAF X
2. Cooler Master Silent Pro M600

Both of the above mentioned components are quite expensive so it would be really nice if someone can suggest any cheaper alternative and if possible something that has the looks of cooler master HAF series as I am not interested in rack mounting the servers.

Comment: Why are you building your own? That's *very* rare and usually a poor decision.

Comment: If your answer is "Because Facebook Do It" I will have you eaten by a pack of wolves.

Comment: You MIGHT (and I suspect you definately will) find that SSI formfactors arn't ATX form factors, and a desktop enclosure might be a VERY bad idea - check *specifically* if the SSI formfactor of your motherboard is supported by whatever case you pick.

Comment: There's just too many things that can go wrong - From cooling (insufficient cooling would be VERY bad - servers push through a LOT of air, often chilled). The premium here is for testing, making sure all the parts work, and in many cases getting you the replacement parts in as short a time frame as possible.

Comment: I'd also turn this question on its head, and wonder, if you could handle your expected loads, and needs with a significantly cheaper desktop. You'd trade off ECC and dual processors for a system thats cooler and quieter - and possibly even double up on systems. As a *desktop* guy who builds his own systems, and my own limited experience with servers, this sounds more sensible. Alternately get an older, standard server, and upgrade parts, but this has its own set of challenges.

Answer (score 7):

It may be less expensive and more cost-effective to buy a prebuilt branded server... with support... and a warranty... and management... and more modularity...

In general, it's nice to have a manufacturer worry about these things.

[**HP**](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/proliant-servers/index.html?facet=ProLiant-ML-Tower#!view=grid&page=1&facet=ProLiant-ML-Tower) and [**Dell**](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-tower-servers) have nice servers.

- Note: If you're planning to use VMware, please consult the [VMWare Hardware Compatibility List](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.vmware.com/go/hcl&ei=A3wHUp-REeeBygHAkIFg&usg=AFQjCNEXuH3H1BNILfm7AMoBNO0jQXhT-g&sig2=-Hy9gp9VIo20pLCUGRcreg).

Comment: I started initially with branded servers like D30 from Lenovo, T420 & T620 from Dell and z820 from HP but the common problem is cost! All the manufacturers quoted me at least 2 to 3 times more than what I need to spend for this assembled system. Moreover, they are giving least choice in selecting the component manufacturers, minimal support and standard 3 year warranty on every component while here I get 5 years on RAM, HDD and 3 on rest of it; even compatibility is assured by manufacturers. So, I am evaluating if I can go ahead with a assembled machine. Thus, questions on PSU & Case.

Comment: @i01000001 The first step is to shop for _actual servers_. Most of those are workstations. The second step is to _never pay retail_. Find a good reseller.